# React Router does not redirect to component

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, switch-statement

I have a route which redirect to my component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route, Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { App } from './components/App/App.jsx'
import './style.css'

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

When i start my project :
localhost:8080/

I am redirected to the main page of the project where i have:
src
node_modules
package.json
webpack.config.js

Then i have to click on src to go to my project.

I dont see where i am going wrong.. 
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your **webpack.config.js** and make sure you have correctly configured your base directory in dev server.

```
...

devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
  compress: true,
  port: 8080
}

...
```

Just replace the folder name **dist** with your projects's public folder name.

Comment: I got only :  Cannot GET /

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

this is my webpack config:

    entry:path.join(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), filename: 'bundle.js' },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        compress: true,
        port: 8080,
        historyApiFallback: true
    }

Comment: in which folder you are having the index.html?

Comment: Ok, I added         contentBase: path.join(__dirname, './src'),
And it works.
Thanks a lot :)